# Отслеживание добавления новых записей

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

Доброго времени суток. Требуется реализовать систему уведомлений, данные о которых хранятся в mongodb и добавляются php-скриптом. 
Собственно, можно ли отслеживать добавление новых записей в базу данных mongodb средствами node.js? Использовать elephant.io не вариант.

Comment: а какая цель ??? почему PHP скрипт неможет передавать в Node факт обновления???

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал socket.io. Делал бы emmit, когда запись добавляется в базу, а на клиенте бы через всё те же сокеты получал данные.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно `setInterval`'ом опрашивать базу на количество записей, и если что, то `dispatch`'ить событие.